# Importing Gtk object from gi.repository

Tags: python, import, introspection, gtk3

Back in my GTK2 days, I could do a

```
from gtk import Clipboard
```

To get access to the clipboard from my program.

Now days, we must import objects introspectively as in:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk
```

I have been scratching my head to see if there is a way to import just an object from Gtk like:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk.Clipboard
```

of course this results in a SyntaxError exception.

Is there a way to do what I'm trying to do? One reason I would like this right now, is that I need a very light way to access the clipboard for a script. I don't want to import all of Gtk, as it is overboard/overkill. I just want the Clipboard class, but I'm curious for other items in the gi.repository (like Notify).

Thanks,

Narnie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very easily.

```
from gi.repository.Gtk import Clipboard
```

Comment: Wonderful! I had searched for syntax for from..import, but never found that you could do it that way (I still don't understand fully how gi.repo works, but I see it must be like other modules in subfolders). I should have thought of trying this!!!

Much appreciated.

Comment: @narnie No problem :) Sometimes it's the obvious things that slow us down

Answer (score 1):

you can't import just an object: you can import a module (Gtk) and   add a name (Clipboard) into current namespace i.e., these should be equivalent:

```
from gi.repository.Gtk import Clipboard
```

and

```
from gi.repository import Gtk
Clipboard = Gtk.Clipboard
```